# Existence and boundedness of partials in neighborhood implies continuity at point

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that if $A\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and if the partials $D_jf$ exist and are bounded in a neighborhood of $a$, then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

The existence and boundedness of partials $D_jf$ in a neighborhood of $a$ means that for some $\varepsilon>0$ and $M>0$, $$\left|\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+te_j)-f(x)}{t}\right|<M$$ for all $x$ such that $|x-a|<\varepsilon$. (Here, $e_j$ is the vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $1$ in position $j$ and $0$ otherwise.)

What we want to prove is the continuity of $f$ at $a$, i.e. $$\lim_{z\rightarrow a}f(z) = f(a).$$ How can we proceed from here?

Comment: I guess this problem is from exercise 4 in section 6 in chapter 2 on p.54 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $f$ is differentiable, hence continuous, along line segments parallel to the axes. So mimic the proof that $C^1$ implies differentiable.

Comment: So for $|h|<\varepsilon$, we have $f(a+h)-f(a)=\sum_{j=1}^mD_jf(q_j)h_j$, where the points $q_j$ belongs to the neighborhood of $a$. Since the partials have an upper bound $M$, and $|h_j|\leq |h|$, we have the sum going to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$. So $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: This is very nice indeed. Thank you, Ted!

Comment: Most welcome :)

Comment: @PJMiller We are going to have then that $\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)+f(a)=0$ and thus, $z=a+h\to a$ as $h\to 0$ with which $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=f(a)$?